# Use a String in another class

Tags: java, class, object, user-interface

I'm working on a program which has 2 classes. The first one is just for the GUI of the program. And in the other is the code to create new files with the needed data.

I want to use the text, wich the user writes in a jTextField. But my problem is, that I'm not able to save the text in a String and than call it in the other class with the code to save the user inputs.

So in the Class *NetworkComponentFrame* is following code:

```
public class NetworkComponentFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/* GUI Code */
public static void main(String args[]) {
String ID = jTextField1.getText();
/* other code */
}}
```

And in the Class *NetworkComponent* is at the moment the following code:

```
public class NetworkComponent {
public static void New(){
NetworkComponentFrame ID = new NetworkComponentFrame();
/*other code */}}
```

The names are just some placeholders. I hope this is enough information to help me solving the problem.

Comment: Perhaps make a public getter/setter for the string that can be called in the other class?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value by creating a constructor NetworkComponent or static property of your NetworkComponentFrame class.
e.g

```
public class NetworkComponentFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/* GUI Code */
public String ID;
public static void main(String args[]) {
ID = jTextField1.getText();
/* other code */
}}
```

in your second class

```
public class NetworkComponent {
public static void New(){
s.o.p(NetworkComponentFrame.ID);
/*other code */}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it the other way around. Instantiate the `NetworkComponent` in the GUI and have a setter method in the `NetworkComponent` and use the text from the text field to set the text in the `NetworkComponent` object.

```
public class NetworkComponent {
    String ID;

    public void setId(String text){
        ID = text;
    }
}

public class NetworkComponentFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    NetworkComponent network = new NetWorkComponent();  <-- NetworkComponent object
    JButton button = new JButton();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    public NetworkComponentFrame(){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String text = textField.getText();
                network.setId(text);                   <-- set the ID here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it sounds funny but the teacher said it, that I have to do it this way :/ but thanks anyway

Comment: Tell your teacher that's bad design, Instantiating your `View/Controller` inside your `Model`. Should be the other way around. See what He/She says.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correct,  u may define String ID out of the main function but in NetworkComponentFrame class as public so u may reach it wherever u want after u create an object from your class.

Eg:

```
public class NetworkComponentFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public String ID_text;
/* GUI Code */
public static void main(String args[]) {
ID_text = jTextField1.getText();
/* other code */
}}


public class NetworkComponent {
public static void New(){
NetworkComponentFrame ID = new NetworkComponentFrame();<
String test = ID.ID_text;
/*other code */}}
```

And something problematic with your example code. Are u sure u are calling **public static void  main** function in a non static object?

Extended: U may also use getters and setters.

Comment: this helped me a lot but if i just do a System.out.println(ID_text); in the NetworkComponentFrame class. --> Output is right. But in the other class is the output "null". where's the problem?